# Positive integer solutions of $ab+1=x^2, ac+1=y^2, bc+1=z^2, x+z=2y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, oeis

A question essentially the same a this one was asked in
[MSE 4479792](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479792/)
without any background details and was deleted by the post author
after I posted a minimal one sentence answer mentioning five OEIS
sequences (more like a long comment).

I propose the question again but including more attention to details
and background.

Prove that all of the positive integer solutions of

$$ ab\!+\!1\!=\!x^2,\: ac\!+\!1\!=\!y^2,\: bc\!+\!1\!=\!z^2,\:
 x+z\!=\!2y,\; 0\!<\!a\!<\!b\!<\!c $$

are given by

$$ a=A001542(n),\quad b=A005319(n),\quad c=A001542(n\!+\!1),\\
 x=A001541(n),\quad y=A001653(n\!+\!1),\quad z=A002315(n) $$

with $0<n.$ These six sequences all satisfy the same linear
recurrence relation but with different initial values. For
example, $\,a_n = 6\,a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\,$ and similarly for the
other five sequences. Notice the condition that $\,x+z=2y\,$ is
equivalent to the condition that $\,x,y,z\,$ are in arithmetic
progression. Without this condition the problem is a special
case of a problem in Diophantus according to
L. E. Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*,
Volume II, Chapter XIX, Section "$xy+a, xz+a, yz+a$ all squares",
pp. $513$-$515$

> Diophantus, III, $12, 13$ and IV, $20$, asked for three numbers
> such that the product of any two increased by a given number $a$
> shall be a square. For $\,a=12,\,$ he found $\,2,2,1/8;\,$ for
> $\,a=-10,\,$ complicated fractions; for $\,a=1, x, x+2, 4x+4.\,$

On page $515$ Dickson states

> Fr. Buchner$^{83}$ treated $xy+1=p^2, xz+1=q^2, yz+1=r^2.$

however both Diophantus and Buchner allow rational solutions and
there is no explicit mention of arithmetic progression in Dickson
for this Diophantine system.

I wonder what is the original source of the arithmetic progression
condition of the square roots for this problem?

An answer to this question requires:

> - **A1**. A proof that the sequences give a solution.
> - **A2**. A proof that there are no other solutions.

A proof of **A1** is elementary given the recursions and induction,
however a proof of **A2** is much harder, but the solutions all
depend on the Pell equation $\,x^2-2a^2=1\,$ and so results from
that theory probably need to be used in the proof.

For convenience and as a check, a small table of sequence values:

$$ \begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|} \hline
  n && a_n & b_n & c_n && x_n & y_n & z_n \\ \hline
 -3 && -70 & -140 & -12 && 99 & 29 & -41 \\ \hline
 -2 && -12 & -24 & -2 && 17 & 5 & -7 \\ \hline
 -1 && -2 & -4 & 0 && 3 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 0 && 0 & 0 & 2 && 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 1 && 2 & 4 & 12 && 3 & 5 & 7 \\ \hline
 2 && 12 & 24 & 70 && 17 & 29 & 41 \\ \hline
 3 && 70 & 140 & 408 && 99 & 169 & 239 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

**NOTE:** all four algebraic conditions are satisfied for all
integer $\,n\,$ but $\,0\!<\!a_n\!<\!b_n\,$ requires $\,0\!<\!n.$

---

**ADDED:** For convenience and to save some wasted effort,
I give an elementary proof of **A1** here using only some simple
algebra of equations and inequalities. First,

$$ b=2a,\quad c=3a+2x,\quad y=a+x,\quad z=2a+x$$

are proved true since they are satisfied by the initial values for
$\,n=1,2\,$ and are preserved by the common linear recursion
relations. The last two equations combined prove the important
$\,x+z=2y\,$ arithmetic progression condition. Also,

$$ a_{n+1} = 3a_n+2x_n,\quad b_{n+1} = 6a_n+4x_n,\quad
   x_{n+1} = 4a_n+3x_n $$

are proved the same way. Given the initial values
$\,0<a_1=2<x_1=3,\,$ and given the previous results, this proves
$\, 0<a_n<x_n<b_n<y_n<z_n<c_n\, $ for all $\,n>0.\,$
Use previous results to get

$$ ab+1-x^2 = ac+1-y^2 = bc+1-z^2 = 2a^2 + 1 - x^2. $$

But $\,2a_0^2+1-x_0^2 = 0\,$ and previous results give
$\,2a_{n+1}^2+1-x_{n+1}^2 = 2a_n^2+1-x_n^2\,$ which implies
this is $0$ for all $\,n.$ This proves

$$ ab\!+\!1=x^2,\quad ac\!+\!1=y^2,\quad bc\!+\!1=z^2. $$

Comment: For the system $xy+T=p^2$ $....$  $z^2-3q^2=T$ The solutions are given through the Pell equations of a general form. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1184227_the_system_is_an_arithmetic_progression

Comment: I found another variant of this solution.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1057324_the_system_is_almost_linear_diophantine_equations

Comment: For convenience, I'll leave the definition of the OEIS sequences above.
$ \ \\ A001542: a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}, a_0=0, a_1=2 \\ A005319: a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}, a_0=0, a_1=4 \\ A001541: a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}, a_0=1, a_1=3 \\ A001653: \text{sequence of $k$ which $2k^2-1$ is square} \\ A002315: a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}, a_n^2-2b_n^2=-1 \text{ for } b_n=A001653(n+1).$

Comment: @individ That is essentially Diophantus as I mentioned quoting Dickson.

Comment: @RDK Thanks for the list of OEIS "NAME"s but, as the first three demonstrate, the best is the common recurrence and the initial values which is included in my small table.

Comment: There are similar tasks.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1183749_system_with_permutations

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607501/multiples-that-are-one-less-than-squares/1607873#1607873

Comment: @individ Thanks for those links, **but** the arithmetic progression condition is **not** required in those problems.